# Cancelable Background Task: NSOperation, GCD or NSThread?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift

I'm new to Swift and don't know how do the following.

When tapping a button I need to kick-off a background task to do some operation and when same button is tapped again I need to stop that very task.

I'm not sure whether to use `NSOperation`, GCD or `NSThread`.

Could someone provide me with a simple example?

Comment: Does the operation need to repeat over and over again until the second button click? Or is it just a single method call? What kind of operation are you trying to perform. Please post any code that you might have tried.

Comment: @ Roman Sausarnes  -there is no need to repeat the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to easily cancel the running task, I recommend using `NSOperation`. GCD doesn't offer a built-in way to cancel executing blocks and using `NSThread` is usually overkill.

The following is a minimal working example. It creates a button inside a view controller. When you tap it, a new `NSBlockOperation` is created and added to an `NSOperationQueue`. When you tap it again, all operations in the queue are cancelled.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Create the queue to run our operation
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton
        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        button.setTitle("Tap me!", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped",
            forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        // Layout the button
        let views: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["button": button]
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-[button]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|-20-[button(44)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
    }

    func buttonTapped() {
        if queue.operationCount == 0 {
            // Create a new operation
            let operation = NSBlockOperation()
            operation.addExecutionBlock { [weak operation] in
                while operation?.cancelled == false {
                    // Do something interesting as long as
                    // the operation was not canceled
                    println("do stuff")
                    sleep(1)
                }
                println("stop doing stuff")
            }

            // Add the operation to the queue (this will also
            // start the operation)
            queue.addOperation(operation)
        } else {
            // Cancel all operations in the queue
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
            // An alternative could be to keep a reference
            // to the single operation and cancel that one
            // instead. The effect is the same in this simple
            // example.
        }
    }

}
```

When you run the above snippet in the simulator you will be able to observe the output on the console.

Comment: thanks for example and i will try and update.

Comment: thanks.. for the sample code.